# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument:

Tags: discord.py

```
Ignoring exception in command addlol:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/discord.py/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 935, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/root/Desktop/discord.py/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/root/Desktop/discord.py/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/root/Desktop/discord.py/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/root/Desktop/discord.py/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: account is a required argument that is missing.
```

Code here:

```py
@bot.command()
async def accounts3(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Accounts #3")
    embed.add_field(name="+martin",value="Sends martin account account",inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.command()
async def addaccounts(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Adding Accounts",description="""You can only add ten accounts per time when using the command, no more or no less\n""") 
    
    embed.add_field(name="+addmartin",value="Format is +addmartin email:pass\n This command can only add 1 account",inline=False)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: when trying to add any info i got this error

Comment: Please provide your code around the line causing the error, this does not help with what you have currently provided

Comment: @bot.command()
async def addaccounts(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Adding Accounts",description="""You can only add ten accounts per time when using the command, no more or no less\n) 
    
    embed.add_field(name="+addmartin",value="Format is +addmartin email:pass\n This command can only add 1 account",inline=False)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided code, it seems the issue seems to occur as you haven't included the closing string mark. Below I have corrected else parts of your code and omitted the multiline string which isn't currently needed.

```py
@bot.command() 
async def addaccounts(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Adding Accounts", description="You can only add ten accounts per time when using the command, no more or no less") 
  embed.add_field(name="+addmartin", value="Format is +addmartin email:pass\n This command can only add 1 account", inline=False)
```

Comment: ok . also concerning the account have separated in 3 categories 
account, account2, account3. martin account is in groupe2 (account2) so i don't know if i have to create a command for each of the groupe?

Comment: before the code above i have this code i wrotten for the diff account group
@bot.command()
async def accounts3(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Accounts #3")
     embed.add_field(name="+martin",value="Sends a martin account",inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="+david",value="Sends a david account",inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

Comment: big thanks i foud the error and fixed it . thanks again for your assistance